# Winding Numbers and Fixed Point Theorems

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems, homotopy-theory, chaos-theory

It is known that winding numbers can be used to prove the existence of fixed point theorems in two dimensions. We look at the vector $f(x)-x$ and if the corresponding winding number does not equal $0$ then we can establish the existence of a fixed point. For example, in the following book http://ifts.zju.edu.cn/profiles/xingangwang/Course2010/download/Yorke-chaos.pdf page 208, winding numbers are used to prove the existence of a fixed point in the case of a covering relation, or correctly aligned window, in two dimensions. In the case of covering relations, or in the case of a Brouwer fixed point (where the map is from a ball to itself), I believe that the winding number of the vector $f(x)-x$ is always one, thus we can prove the existence of one fixed point. In the case of a horseshoe map (see the previous book page 214), however, we can have that the winding number is two (one can easily verify this). We also know that the horseshoe map has two fixed points. So my question is the following, does anyone know whether a winding number $i$ establishes $i$ fixed points, or can we have, for example, a case where the winding number is two but only one fixed point exists. Thanks.

Comment: You should read about the Morse Index Theorem, and the index of a zero of a vector field. There are vector fields with zeroes of index two, and the field on a small surrounding circle will have a winding number of $2$; an alternative is that such a curve might contain two zeroes of index 1, or a zero of index 3 and another of index $-1$, of all sorts of other possibilities.

Comment: @JohnHughes This is perfect, thanks. Do you know if area preserving functions ever have a fixed point with the absolute value of the index greater than $1$?

Comment: I don't know, no. That's a fine question, but you should ask it as its own question rather than morphing this one.